# CSS , header allignment

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I'm trying to learn React a bit more in-depth.
I'm building a map component and I'm trying to create a header for the page

this is my main component render:

```js
return (
    <div>
    <HeaderContainer>
        <HeaderBackground>
            <Header>{"PASTURE TIME"}</Header>
                <ImageContainer></ImageContainer>
        </HeaderBackground>
    </HeaderContainer>
      <ProcessorMapContainer>
        <Map {...props} />
      </ProcessorMapContainer>
    </div>
  );
```

this is the Header stuff styles:

```js
export const HeaderContainer = styled.div`
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const HeaderBackground = styled.div`
  background-color: #ffffff;
`;

export const Header = styled.h1`
  height: 100px;
  font-family: ${fontFamilies.SourceSansProLight};
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #009cde;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 1;
`;

export const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100px;
  width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(${allflex_logo}) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 1;
`;
```

no matter how I play with ImageContainer and the Header (h1), I can't seem to make them appear in the same row, without expanding the entire header.

the header right now:
[image: current header]

the header I'm trying to achieve:
[image: design]

The thing I don't get is, how to align them in the same row, and why the sub-elements (h1 and the image) can modify the component above them (when I'm changing the height and width it modifies the white background)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `flex-direction: column` from your `HeaderContainer`, and remove the `HeaderBackground` component - it is messing up your attempts at `flex` as it is the only child. You can put your background style on just the `HeaderContainer`.

Then the `Header` and `ImageContainer` components will be the children of `HeaderContainer`, and `display: flex` will make them on one line.

To get that screenshot you want, you will want to add a third component with "Producer Name", and add the style `align-items: space-between` to `HeaderContainer` to get the three child components to space out like that.